# PL/SQL function that returns a value from a table after a check

Tags: sql, database, function, plsql

I am new to php and sql and I am building a little game to learn a little bit more of the latter.

This is my simple database of three tables:

```
 -- *********** SIMPLE MONSTERS DATABASE

 CREATE TABLE  monsters (

 monster_id         VARCHAR(20),
 haunt_spawn_point  VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
 monster_name       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 level_str          VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 creation_date      DATE NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT monster_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (monster_id)
 );

 -- ****************************************

 CREATE TABLE  spawntypes (

 spawn_point            VARCHAR(5),
 special_tresures       VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
 maximum_monsters       NUMBER NOT NULL,
 unitary_experience     NUMBER NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT spawn_point_pk PRIMARY KEY (spawn_point)
 );

 -- ****************************************

 CREATE TABLE  fights (

 fight_id           NUMBER,
 my_monster_id      VARCHAR(20),
 foe_spawn_point    VARCHAR(5),
 foe_monster_id     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 fight_start        TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 fight_end          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 total_experience   NUMBER NOT NULL
 loot_type          NUMBER NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT my_monster_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (my_monster_id)
 REFERENCES monsters (monster_id),

 CONSTRAINT foe_spawn_point_fk FOREIGN KEY (foe_spawn_point)
 REFERENCES spawntypes (spawn_point),

 CONSTRAINT fight_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (fight_id)
 );
```

Given this data how can I easily carry out this two tasks:

1) I would like to create a pl/sql function that passing only a fight_id as a parameter and given the foe_spawn_point (inside the fight table) return the unitary_experience that is related to this spawn point referencing the spawntypes table, how can I do it? :-/  [f(x)]

In order to calculate the total experience earned from a fight (unitary_experience * fight_length) I have created a function that given a particular fight will subtract the fight_end with the fight_start so now I know how long the fight lasted. [f(y)]

2) is it possible to use this two functions (multiply the result that they returns) during the database population task?

INSERT INTO fights VALUES(.... , f(x) * f(y), 'loot A');

in order to populate all the total_experience entries inside the fights table?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you don't generally talk about building functions to do things.  The building blocks of SQL are queries, views, and stored procedures (most SQL dialects *do* have functions, but that is not the place to start).

So, given a variable with $FIGHTID you would fetch the unitary experience with a simple query that uses the `join` operation:

```
select unitary_experience
from fight f join
     spawnTypes st
     on st.spawn_point = f.foe_spawn_point
where fightid = $FIGHTID
```

If you have a series of values to insert, along with a function, I would recommend using the `select` form of `insert`:

```
insert into fights(<list of columns, total_experience)
    select <list of values>,
           ($FIGHT_END - $FIGHT_START) * (select unitary_experience from spawnTypes where spawnType ='$SPAWN_POINT)
```

One comment about the tables.  It is a good idea for all the ids in the table to be integers that are auto-incremented.  In Oracle you do this by creating a sequence (and it is simpler in most other databases).

Comment: Hello Gordon, thank you for the really good explanation :) I have still a doubt in the join operation should't be ON st.spawn_point = f.for_spawn_point? I got confused

Comment: @Jonathan . . . Yes, that was a typo.